# Using AlarmManager to start a service from another service

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I'm writing an Android code under Eclipse in which I shall handle two services: `MyService1` and `MyService2`. The first one is triggered by `AlaramManager` from the `MainActivity' as follows:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, NumSec);
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), MyService1.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(), 0, i, 0);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
```

This is OK and well works.
Now, I am going to start the second service `MyService2` from `MyService1` again using `AlarmManager` in the same manner. But there is an error in this line of my code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyService1.this, MyService2.class);
```

I know that the function `Intent` has two arguments and the first one is of type `Context`. I tried some other ways but non of them works! For example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService2.class);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), MyService2.class);
```

Any suggestion?!
Thanks in advance.

[Edited]
My first service is as follows:

```
public class MyService1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
     public void onReceive(Context con, Intent arg1) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        Intent i = new Intent(con, MyUpService.class);
        PendingIntent pint = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, i, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from the first Service? Do you create the Intent on another thread?

Comment: Dear @momo I've added my first service.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PendingIntent.getService to start service, instead of PendingIntent.getBroadcast.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 0):

in your callback has `Context Object`

```
public void onReceive(Context con, Intent arg1) {
}
```

So your can use this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(con, MyService1.class);
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(con, MyService2.class);
```